# Django: Does chaining filter() functions result in the same SQL as using multiple kwargs?

Tags: django, django-orm

In Django, do the following two snippets produce the same underlying SQL query?

```
qs = MyModel.objects.filter(group=1, type=2)
```

and

```
qs = MyModel.objects.filter(group=1).filter(type=2)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends actually, on whether there are joins or spanned lookups, especially through `M2M` relationship. For example

```
>>> print User.objects.filter(groups__gt=1).filter(groups__lt=2).query
SELECT "auth_user"."id", "auth_user"."username", "auth_user"."first_name", "auth_user"."last_name", "auth_user"."email", "auth_user"."password", "auth_user"."is_staff", "auth_user"."is_active", "auth_user"."is_superuser", "auth_user"."last_login", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user" INNER JOIN "auth_user_groups" ON ("auth_user"."id" = "auth_user_groups"."user_id") INNER JOIN "auth_user_groups" T4 ON ("auth_user"."id" = T4."user_id") WHERE ("auth_user_groups"."group_id" > 1  AND T4."group_id" < 2 )

>>> print User.objects.filter(groups__gt=1, groups__lt=2).query
SELECT "auth_user"."id", "auth_user"."username", "auth_user"."first_name", "auth_user"."last_name", "auth_user"."email", "auth_user"."password", "auth_user"."is_staff", "auth_user"."is_active", "auth_user"."is_superuser", "auth_user"."last_login", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user" INNER JOIN "auth_user_groups" ON ("auth_user"."id" = "auth_user_groups"."user_id") WHERE ("auth_user_groups"."group_id" < 2  AND "auth_user_groups"."group_id" > 1 )
```

Comment: Interesting.  Is one of those more efficient than the other?

Comment: @Ben They produce different SQLs, the second one has less join thus is more efficient. Also, it's better to be careful when constructing some complex querysets like those in the example: they might introduce extra joins. If generated queries are same, the `.filter().filter()` produces another new `QuerySet`, thus is a bit slower and costly than the single `.filter()`, but the performance penalty is trivial normally.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**

### More on `QuerySet`s

More documentation on chaining `QuerySet`'s `filter`s: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#chaining-filters

### Difference between two mentioned calls

There is some difference, however. With every `filter()` method call you receive new `QuerySet` object, so doing this call:

```
qs = Model.objects.filter(group=1, type=2)
```

seems to be wiser (in terms of performance and amount of code you need to write) than doing this call:

```
qs = Model.objects.filter(group=1).filter(type=2)
```

### `QuerySet`s are lazy

As in the title of this section, just getting `QuerySet` in return does not mean the query has been executed on the database. It is just a container of the conditions that will be used to perform the query.

[Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy) says:

> `QuerySet`s are lazy -- the act of creating a `QuerySet` doesn't involve any database *activity*. You can stack filters together all day long, and Django won't actually run the query until the `QuerySet` is *evaluated*.

Answer (score 1):

Both are same and i even checked the sql query being generated.They are the same.

```
CreateCardTrack.objects.filter(email='vivek').filter(id=1)
>>> connection.queries
[{'time': '0.000', 'sql': u'SELECT `CreateCardTrack`.`id`, `CreateCardTrack`.`email`, `    CreateCardTrack`.`date` FROM `CreateCardTrack` WHERE (`CreateCardTrack`.`email` =     vivek.s  AND `CreateCardTrack`.`id` = 1 ) LIMIT 21'}]
>>> CreateCardTrack.objects.filter(email='vivek.s',id=1)
[<CreateCardTrack: CreateCardTrack object>]
>>> #SELECT `CreateCardTrack`.`id`, `CreateCardTrack`.`email`, `CreateCardTrack`.`date` FROM `CreateCardTrack` WHERE (`CreateCardTrack`.`email` = vivek.s  AND `CreateCardTrack`.`id` = 1 ) LIMIT 21
```