# Filtering records with AND requests with django-taggits

Tags: django, tags, django-taggit

I'm trying to find records which have both tags at the same time with the following code:

```
values = s.split(',')

query = Q()

for item in values:
    query &= Q(tags__name__iexact=item.strip())

photos = Photo.objects.filter(query).distinct();
```

Which returns empty queryset. Django-taggit documentation provides with this example only

```
 Food.objects.filter(tags__name__in=["delicious"])
```

Which returns all the record containing *any* tag, but not both at the same time

*upd*

This is how I did that in my code with "filter chaining".

```
photos = Photo.objects
for value in values:
    photos = photos.filter(tags__name__icontains=value.strip())
```

Which actually means

```
photos.filter(...).filter(...).filter(...)...
```

It is probably superslow, but works for me.

Comment: Could you post the query of photos (`print(photos.query)`)?

Comment: @ElwinArens here is an example: http://pastebin.com/3PFivTqr

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best way of doing it, but it's definitely an easy one :-)

```
values = s.split(',')
sets = [];

# first get a list of sets of photos containing one tag at a time
for tag in values:
    sets.append(set(Photo.objects.filter(tags__name__in=[tag])))

# now intersect all sets to get only photos with all tags
photos = set.intersection(*sets)
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure that it's not super slow, especially with big request. This is how I did it at the end (added to the original post)

Comment: Well, it definitely will get super slow for a high number of values, as it hits the database for each one. Chaining the filters is definitely a better way because the generated SQL will only hit the DB once... and probably end-up with an AND statement, which is what you really want.  Thanks for sharing that.

Comment: ... and you should put your updated code as an answer, because that's a good answer to your question.

Comment: ... and concerning the performance, here is a nice question about chaining filters: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11026401/466275

Comment: ... and I was wrong, it doesn't just end up with an AND query. Just did the test with `print Photo.objects....filter(...).filter(...).query` and the generated SQL looks really complex with a lot of INNER JOINS... but at the end it IS far better than hitting the DB many times :-)

Comment: thanks a lot for comments. At least it works the way I want it to work :)